# Javascript not reading value from hidden textBox - JQuery C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm a non-specialist with JavaScript / JQuery and I'm having trouble figuring out why my script doesn't work.  When my C# page loads, I have a hidden textBox txtHiddenKeywordArray which gets dynamically filled with comma separated values like...   horse, buggy, track

I'm trying to use the highlight functionality in jquery.highlight-3.js where I have a label text field that will contain and highlight the words in the keywords list.  I'm using the script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var myString = document.getElementById('<%=txtHiddenKeywordArray.ClientID%>').val()
    myArray = myString.split(" ");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
            $("p").highlight(myArray[i])
    });
</script>
```

Here is the textBox declaration :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHiddenKeywordArray" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

It worked great when I hard coded the values of var myString. I've tried researching it and keep seeing the same example of the way I have it done.  The page does use a MasterPage.  Could this affect it?

Any idea how I can get the script to see the values from the textbox?  Do I need a RegisterStartUpScript or something?  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried using display:none along with visibility:false?

Comment: have you checked txtHiddenKeywordArray is filled or not and also is javascript code is on same page or in external .js file

Comment: Hi, yes, the txtbox does get filled with the proper values.  the textbox does not have a 'display property" Thanks

Comment: Each of modern browsers have built in JavaScript debuggers.... consider stepping through JavaScript to see what is happening.

Answer (score 6):

SET

```
style="display:none;"
```

INSTEAD of using

```
Visible="false"
```

for your TextBox.

If you set TextBox to visible=false. Then, textbox will not be rendered in the html. So, will not be accessible.

Eg.:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHiddenKeywordArray" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

JS Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">      
$(document).ready(function () {
 var myString = $('#<%=txtHiddenKeywordArray.ClientID%>').val();
    myArray = myString.split(" ");  
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        $("p").highlight(myArray[i])
});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Kapil... I tried that too and it doesn't work. :( any other ideas?  Thanks so much for trying though to everybody!

Comment: That was it!!!  I didn't realize when you said change the display that CSS could actually solve the problem!!  Thank you so much for explaining that a little further!!!  How much do I owe you Kapil!!?? :)

Comment: +1 for fixing the visibility issue. That's what I was trying to diagnose with the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = document.getElementById('<%=txtHiddenKeywordArray.ClientID%>').val()
```

should be

```
var myString = $('#<%=txtHiddenKeywordArray.ClientID%>').val();
```

because `.val()` works on jQuery object.

You can also try

```
var myString = document.getElementById('<%=txtHiddenKeywordArray.ClientID%>').value;
```

Comment: Hi codeParadox...I tried that and it doesn't work. :( any other possibilities?  Thanks!!

Comment: @PaulvanValkenburgh I have updated my code and I missed a `#` in my code, check that and try

Comment: Hi codePara.... neither of those work either... hard coding it's perfect and I know the values are going into the text box on page load.  ...stumped ... thank you !!

Comment: Thanks again codePara ... it was that I needed to change the CSS to display:none and take out the visible=false for the text box.  Appreciate all of your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var myString = $('#<%=txtHiddenKeywordArray.ClientID%>').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The advice of @Kapil and @thecodeparadox is necessary. You also need to move the first two lines of javascript inside the *$document.ready(...)*:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myString = $('#<%=txtHiddenKeywordArray.ClientID%>').val();
    myArray = myString.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        $("p").highlight(myArray[i])
});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Joel  Thanks for the message but it sill isn't highlighting.  I'm stumped because when I replace the line in my original code var myString = $('#<%=txtHiddenKeywordArray.ClientID%>').val(); and just hard code it with var myString = "joe pete sue";, it works great!  Thanks you!

Comment: Try adding the line alert(myString) immediately after the var myString, so that you can see that you are actually getting the values you expect from your hidden field. By the way, can you show your code for the hidden field? Maybe there is something wrong with the HTML. If there is, jQuery won't find it.

Comment: Hi Joel. I added the alert and it popped up 'Undefined', so the value isn't arriving.  The text box is <asp:TextBox ID="txtHiddenKeywordArray" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox> Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Joel .... Kapil's solution did it.  Thank you so much for your help as all of you guys are so helpful!!  What's the charge for this service anyway?  :)  Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome. The "fee" is to upvote the answers that helped, and be sure to accept the answer by @Kapil.  If you ask questions and don't accept any answers, in the future people will not bother to answer your questions. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the raw asp.net control tag to your selector.
Just the name of the `id` should work.
This should work.

Plain Old Javascript should be

```
var myString = document.getElementById('txtHiddenKeywordArray').value;
```

jQuery should be

```
var myString = $('#txtHiddenKeywordArray').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing you textbox to a hiddenfield (as that is what you are trying to do).

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtHiddenKeywordArray" Value="horse, track" />
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($("input[id$='txtHiddenKeywordArray']").val());
});
```

works just fine :)